# Rendering in reponse to the first post only of a multiple post: is this possible?

Tags: wicket

Our users return to our web site from an external site, to a URL which is passed to the external site as a user leaves our site. Returning to our site involves a status update which is persisted to the application's datastore.

I have implemented a check upon return to our web site, which prevents a multiple write to our datastore and thus makes the operation idempotent.

A typical order of events is:

1. First post to our landing web page (web page instance 1 is constructing)
2. First post passes check (data not processed before)
3. Data persistence begins (still in the web page constructor)
4. Second post to our landing web page (web page instance 2 is constructing), which is in the same session and browser window as the first post
5. Second post fails check (data has been, or is being, processed already)
6. Web page instance 2 constructor completes (with no persistence to datastore) and web response is served to the user
7. Web page instance 1 constructor completes (after having persisted to datastore)
8. The user does not see page instance 1 in their browser.

The end result is that, even though the second post is made after the first, the second post "completes" faster to the user and the user's web browser shows instance 2 of the page, not instance 1.

My questions are:

- Is there any way I can have the first, datastore-processing, page instance shown to the user (and thus "throw away" the second page instance)?
- If so, can this be done without using AJAX?

I would appreciate any assistance greatly.

**My development environment**

- Web framework:     Wicket 1.5.7
- Java:              1.6.0_33; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.8-b03
- Web server system: Google App Engine for Java version 1.6.6
- Operating system:  Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition version 2002 SP3 (version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_GB)
- IDE:               NetBeans IDE 7.1.2 (Build 201204101705)

Comment: Can't you just let page instance 2 wait for the result of data processing?

Comment: ... e.g. by blocking in your app's service layer?

Comment: @svenmeier Thanks for the tip. Even though we are using Google App Engine, we use a `WebSession` to hold the data process check data. (Any datastore updating for the same stuff will be in the context of the same session.) I shall look into amending the data structure of the concurrency check to see if this can be used to exchange useful data between the two page instances (which may be running on separate JVMs).

Comment: Just to clarify, are the two requests not in the same session?

Comment: @Carl-EricMenzel: Yes, indeed they are. I have just edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: Why is there a second post anyway if it contains the same data? Is it resend because the response is taking to long?

Comment: Both requests should just redirect to a result page. The first submit can process the data first, the second can redirect immediately. The result page should refresh itself until the data processing is complete.

Comment: @Nicktar: The external site sends the request. Under certain circumstances, it can send it twice. So I need to be ready for that.

Comment: @Carl-EricMenzel: Thanks. I'll ponder that, but I am about to finish development of my data process checking changes. The second page instance pauses to allow the first page instance to complete processing.

Comment: Just to get this straight... The external site, not the client's browser is sending these requests? Then how is this tied to the page, the client is served?

Comment: @Nicktar: Yes, The external site is sending these requests. The tie-in to our Wicket WebPage is made by our Wicket app passing a bookmarkable URL to the external site as part of the processing of handing over to the external site. The external site posts to this URL when it is done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it... As far as I understand HTTP, a client (the browser) sends a request (GET or POST) to a server and gets a response (the page). There is no place for a third party to add any POST-requests...

Comment: @Nicktar 1. A user clicks a link on our Wicket app to visit the external site. Within this link a URL is present which the external site stores for later use.  2. The user uses the external site's web pages.  3. When the user has completed his or her process on the external site, the external site uses the previously-stored URL to post to it.  4. Our Wicket app begins construction of a `WebPage` instance as a result of the external site posting to the previously-stored URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @svenmeier for your first tip. My solution follows this approach. I have decided to have page instance 2 wait repeatedly if necessary instead of following @Carl-EricMenzel's suggestion of redirecting.

Referring to my order of events as set out in my question, step 6 is replaced by:

6.1  If data is being processed already, page instance 2 waits repeatedly whilst checking after each wait.

6.2  After all the waiting, page instance 1 will have completed step 7 (and 8). If not, then page instance 2 completes construction.

6.3  If the data processing of instance 1 succeeded then page instance 2 shows success to the user.

6.4  If the data processing of instance 1 failed then page instance 2 processes the data and shows the result (success/fail) to the user.